# How to execute multiple instances of Selenium on MacOS using shell scripts

Tags: python, windows, macos, selenium-webdriver

I have a testing script called `sel.py` to run Selenium with Python:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

def main(website_url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    driver.get(website_url)
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    website_url = input("Enter the URL of the website to be automated: ")
    main(website_url)
```

On my Windows laptop, I can execute multiple batch files, lets say `sel.bat`. On the first terminal I enter 'https://www.google.com.pe/' and when executing the batch file again I enter 'https://stackoverflow.com/'. Result: I have two Google Chrome windows opened with the said websites.

But when I'm on my Macbook, I do the same, this time with shell scripts `sel.sh`. The first instance works fine, but then when entering the second url on the second terminal (while the first shell script is running and with Google Chrome opened), I get this error:

```
user@MacBook-Air-de-user testing_app % ./sel.sh
    Enter the URL of the website to be automated: https://stackoverflow.com/
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/user/Codigo/testing_app/sel.py", line 15, in <module>
        main(website_url)
      File "/Users/user/Codigo/testing_app/sel.py", line 8, in main
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
      File "/Users/user/Codigo/testing_app/testing_app_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 49, in __init__
        super().__init__(
      File "/Users/user/Codigo/testing_app/testing_app_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 51, in __init__
        self.service.start()
      File "/Users/user/Codigo/testing_app/testing_app_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 97, in start
        self.assert_process_still_running()
      File "/Users/user/Codigo/testing_app/testing_app_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 110, in assert_process_still_running
        raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /Users/user/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64/116.0.5845.96/chromedriver-mac-arm64/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -9
```

My final purpose is to execute at the same time multiple shell scripts with different variables to use as command-line argument for the script.

'sel.bat'

```
@echo off

set "VENV_DIR=C:\Users\user\Desktop\testing_app\testing_app_env"

call "%VENV_DIR%\Scripts\activate.bat"
"%VENV_DIR%\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\testing_app\sel.py"

pause
```

'sel.sh'

```
#!/bin/bash

VENV_DIR="/Users/user/Codigo/testing_app/testing_app_env"

source "$VENV_DIR/bin/activate"
"$VENV_DIR/bin/python" "/Users/user/Codigo/testing_app/sel.py"

deactivate
```